# High memory footprint when unmarshalling large slice of strings

Tags: performance, go, memory, memory-management

We are observing high memory footprint in our program when it unmarshalls JSON response that contains large slice (for example, one million UUIDs).

I tried to simulate this with some simple benchmark, the program will make API call to some dummy server that will return 1M UUIDs as response, then unmarshal the response into a struct.
Code snippet:

```
type response struct {
    ItemID []string
}

func main() {

    benchRes := testing.Benchmark(func(b *testing.B) {
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

            res := response{}
            err = json.Unmarshal(body, &res)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            resp.Body.Close()
        }
    })
    fmt.Println(benchRes)
    fmt.Println(benchRes.MemString())
}
```

The output is

```
      2         532327650 ns/op
232710540 B/op   1000147 allocs/op
```

Which is more or less confirm our previous observation, i.e. big memory footprint (~200MB) just to process 1M UUID which should be around 40MB (?)

One speculation I can think of is due to multiple memory allocations to grow the slice capacity (?).

The problem is worsen by the fact that memory doesn't seem to be reclaimed back by OS over time, i.e. RSS keeps on increasing over time and program get OOM killed after some time.
We understand that this might be due to how Go GC works, coupled with MADV_FREE flag that's being used.

Therefore, now we are trying to figure out if there is any way to at least reduce memory footprint of Go JSON Unmarsal for our use case.
Thank you!

Update:
Tried to decode token-by-token, memAlloc reduced from 238MB to 176MB

```
65.50MB 41.52% 41.52%    80.50MB 51.03%  encoding/json.(*scanner).error
      46MB 29.16% 70.68%       46MB 29.16%  encoding/json.(*decodeState).literalStore
   31.27MB 19.82% 90.49%   157.77MB   100%  main.main.func2
      15MB  9.51%   100%       15MB  9.51%  encoding/json.quoteChar
```

Seems similar with https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10335

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308109/4466350

Comment: Assuming you run some version of Linux, the OS will not and cannot reclaim the memory.

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon for the link, tried and it does reduce memAlloc from 238MB to 176MB according to go bench, wondering if we can optimize even further, I edited original post to include pprof for this suggested approach. `json.(*scanner).error` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @Erik actually we do observe this behaviour (i.e. OOM killed is inevitable), but numerous online articles always mention "OS will reclaim memory when under memory pressure". I'm yet able to find good explanation for this, could you please elaborate more on why OS never reclaim the memory back?

Comment: The OS can only reclaim memory that it itself uses for other things, such as filesystem caches. Memory that has been allocated by a process must be released by that process (and Go does this, it just takes a while because allocations and releases are somewhat costly, so it's generally better to hold on to allocated memory in case it's needed in the short term).

Comment: Have you ever run into OOM killing? Aside from the fact that this can for all practical purposes with a swap partition (no OOM killing then, but potentially heavy swapping), this whole thing sounds to me like premature optimization. Have you run a load test against you application? I doubt the memory consumption will increase linearly.

Comment: Aside from that: any reason to buffer the response body into `body`, when you could as good do `json.Unmarshal(resp.Body,&res}`? Furthermore, `&res` should imho be of type `[]string`. If I am not mistaken, the way you do it, you might have a bunch of unnecessary copying going on.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Yes, we are hitting OOM killed once every 1 - 2 days now, hence the attempt to optimize here. In fact, we try to convert that snippet into some function and call it multiple times, memory easily increases to 2GB+ and OOM killed eventually.
Good catch, converted to `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&res)`, but doesn't seem to reduce memory much. And please excuse the over-simplified struct, in real code, we still have other fields aside from []string, but I omit them for brevity.

Comment: You unmarshal into an empty slice. As json.Unmarshal doesn't know how large this slice is going to append to it. From the documentation of encoding/json.Unmarshal: "To unmarshal a JSON array into a slice, Unmarshal resets the slice length to zero and then appends each element to the slice. As a special case, to unmarshal an empty JSON array into a slice, Unmarshal replaces the slice with a new empty slice."

Comment: So when you 1 million of elements and your slice is full append will allocate a larger one, let's say 1.2 million elements and copy the existing over. During that time you have 2.2 million entries (but you need just 1.2 one). So try preallocating the `ItemID` field to avoid this copying. (Or even better: Work on the stream, instead of reading everything into memory and processing it afterwards read and process each UUID.)

Comment: @Volker Yes, we did suspect the slice allocations, and thanks to @mh-cbon link, I tried to work directly on the stream + pre-allocate the slice with the right capacity as you suggested. It does bring down the memoryAlloc to 176MB, but there is a big chunk of alloc (~60MB) from `json.(*Scanner).error` now (refer to the pprof that I attached at original question). Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Again: try allocating some swap. the OOM killer usually only hits if no swap is allocated. That is a stop gap measure only, though. https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Comment: can you share the full extract of pprof, and the updated code.

Comment: @mh-cbon updated code here: https://play.golang.org/p/lMpD8jjBwSo and full pprof: https://pastebin.com/8tf3383m

Comment: at line 61, you are not stream processing the data, you are bulking. Your best option to solve your OOM is to rework memory usage of this program.

Comment: @mh-cbon I'm not sure what you meant with "bulking", the thing is we do need all the UUIDs inside a slice, hence we need to append them eventually into the struct. Furthermore, to me the memory overhead now is mostly on `s.error(c, "after top-level value")` I'm not sure why Scanner creates this error objects, any suggestion on how to avoid this?

Comment: take a look alternative json coder for example https://github.com/mailru/easyjson