# Reading large key:value JSON files in Golang

Tags: json, go

I'm stuck on a task at the moment, and that is reading data from a large JSON file in Go. I've found some of the approaces for JSON files with a structure like this:

```json
[
    {
        "key1":"value1"
    },
    {
        "key2":"value2"
    }
]
```

But in my case, I have the following structure of JSON:

```json
{
    "key1": {
        "nestedKey1": "value1"
    },
    "key2": {
        "nesteKey2": "value2"
    }
}
```

I also mention that my JSON is saved in a local .json file and can get quite large (> 1 GB) that cannot be read at once. Is there any good methods to read it and parse it partially?

Comment: Use `json.Decoder` and parse manually.

Comment: Also see [Decode JSON as it is still streaming in via net/http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307219/decode-json-as-it-is-still-streaming-in-via-net-http/44308109#44308109)

Comment: @Зелёный it does not, i've tried it before, it solves the first case i have mentioned in the question