# Handling 10 mb files with GoLang in a container

Tags: json, go

I am currently working on project which require processing on a Jason files (like json.Marshal(), json.Unmarshal() and more), we are working with around 10 MB files and there is an issue we are facing, the Golang library is not able to handle the file, it's crashing. As we are working with docker container, there is limited memory of 25 MB. Can anyone suggest a way to handle 10 MB Jason files efficiently in Golang ? And if possible, a faster way to Marshal and Unmarshal ?

- We tried to increase the memory to 50 MB, but same issue of crashing. 50 MB is max we can use.

Comment: If you only have 25 MB memory, you shouldn't process 10 MB JSON files. If you must, you could try event-driven JSON processing, but it's more complex. If you can, split the input JSON into multiple fragments and process them sequentially.

Comment: Also do use `json.Decoder` instead of reading the complete JSON into memory and using `json.Unmarshal()` after that. The former likely to use much less memory. As an example for event-driven JSON processing, see [Decode JSON as it is still streaming in via net/http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307219/decode-json-as-it-is-still-streaming-in-via-net-http/44308109#44308109)

Comment: thanks I'll try there things

Comment: it worked use decode is much better!